# Is 'Protection' an acceptable Java class name

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

I'm trying my best to write good readable, code, but often have doubts in my work!

I'm creating some code to check the status of some protected software, and have created a class which has methods to check whether the software in use is licensed (there is a separate Licensing class).

I've named the class 'Protection',  which is currently accessed, via the creation of an appProtect object.  The methods in the class allow to check a number of things about the application, in order to confirm that it is in fact licensed for use.

Is 'Protection' an acceptable name for such a class?

I read somewhere that if you have to think to long in names of methods, classes, objects etc, then perhaps you may not be coding in an Object Oriented way.  I've spent a lot of time thinking about this before making this post, which has lead me to doubt the suitability of the name!

In creating (and proof reading) this post, I'm starting to seriously doubt my work so far.  I'm also thinking I should probably rename the object to applicationProtection rather than appProtect (though am open to any comments on this too?).  I'm posting non the less, in the hope that I'll learn something from others views/opinions, even if they're simply confirming I've "done it wrong"!

EDIT:
Thanks for the responses, and apologies if it wasn't a 'valid' question.  I was going to go for licenseChecker (thanks @millimoose) though another thread suggested 'Protector' which seems more fitting, as the class acts depending on whether there is a valid license.

Comment: "a class which has methods to check whether the software in use is licensed" – then call it `LicenceChecker`. A class name should be a noun describing what it represents, or what it does. (Class names that are nounified verbs seem odd, but seeing as most design patterns have classes encapsulating processes or actions it can't be that bad a code smell.)

Comment: Thanks.  Is this because a 'licenseChecker' is a thing(noun?), whereas a 'Protection' isn't?

Comment: I think it is a fine name, but that is just me. This will likely be closed very soon, but try re-posting this question at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @jonny It's because `Protection` doesn't say what the class does and could mean a lot of things. `CopyProtection` or `CopyProtectionCheck` would also be an improvement though.

Comment: This isnt the best fitting response but its worth looking at: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html

Answer (score 1):

Classes are blueprints of objects. Objects represent real-world concepts. So, the name of a class should simply reflect the name you use in the real world when you refer to that concept. In your case Protection (even though a valid and not necessarily bad name) is not very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Read the code out loud and see how it sounds to you.  Obviously it won't sound perfect, but if you were reading the names of the classes, instances, and methods to someone who is a non-programmer they should sound reasonable to them, and almost tell a story.  I think the pattern of a [DSL](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/4/20/writing-domain-specific-languages) is a pretty good one to follow in many cases.  This isn't super common in Java programming, and doesn't always fit the problem, but I think it gives a nice guide for class and method names.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you want to name your classes something that refers to a *role*, rather than an *action*. Since you will be creating instances of the class that interact with other objects, it's clear that each object in your application plays a certain role in the grand scheme.

I think the name `LicenseChecker` suggested by @millimoose is perfect for your case, as it accurately reflects the *role* of the class.